# How to write a predicate doublelist(L, R)?

Tags: lambda, prolog

How to write a predicate doublelist(L, R) with L is list of numbers, R is also a list and has the same length as L and each element is doubled up.

Example:

```
?- doublelist([-1, 0, 3], L).  
L = [-2, 0, 6].
```

I'm a prolog beginner, I confuse to write one myself. Please help.

Comment: Please show us your latest failed attempt at writing this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing down your example:

```
double_list([-1,0,3],[-2,0,6]).
```

This is a perfectly valid Prolog. You can use it in all kinds of directions:

```
?- double_list([-1,0,3],L).
L = [-2,0,6].

?- double_list([-1,0,3],[-2,0,6]).
Yes.
```

So, now you need to make it more general. As a first step, write down what it means:

```
double_list([-1,0,3],[-2,0,6]):-
    (-2) is 2*(-1),
    0    is 2*???,
    6    is ?????.
```

Next step, substitute variables for numbers:

```
double_list([-1,0,3],[-2,0,6]):-
    A1 is (-1), B1 is (-2), B1 is 2*A1,
    A2 ????,    B2 ????,    B2 is 2*??,
    A3 ????,    B3 ????,    B3 ???????.
```

Can you continue from this? Do you see the pattern?

```
double_list([X1,X2,X3],[Y1,Y2,Y3]):-
    ......
```

Now you have a predicate that works for all lists of length 3. Then,

```
double_list([X1 | T1], [Y1 | Z1]):-
    ......

double_list( [], ZN) :- ZN = ???? .
```

Comment: double_list([X1 | T1], [Y1 | Z1]) :-  
    Y1 is 2*X1, double_list(T1, Z1).
double_list( [], ZN) :- ZN = [].

Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

```
    maplist(\I^D^(D is 2*I), Is, Ds).
```

This uses the higher-order predicate [`maplist/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist) and lambda expressions as defined in [library(lambda)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl).

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use

```
double_list(Is,Ds) :- findall(D,(member(I,Is),D is 2*I),Ds).
```

For those who don't feel comfortable with maplist.